# Disabling an individual button in a SetterBar

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I'm trying to create a set of `SetterBar` within my `DynamicModule`, but I want to have it so that an individual button gets disabled if a certain button is pressed on a different setter bar. Here is the relevant code:

```
DynamicModule[{Clo = 1, Cp = 0, Cprj = 0},
 GraphicsColumn[{
   Column[
    {Style[
      "Location of C", 
      FontSize -> 10],
     SetterBar[
      Dynamic[Clo], {0 -> "Origin", 
       1 -> "Tip of B"}]},
    Alignment -> Center, Background -> None],
   Column[{
     Style["Location of (A.C)A^", FontSize -> 10],
     SetterBar[Dynamic[{Cp, Cprj}], {
       {0, 0} -> 
        Style["Origin of C", FontSize -> 9],
       {1, 0} -> 
        Style["Tip of C", FontSize -> 9], {0, 1} -> 
        Style["End of (A.B)A^", 
         GrayLevel[Dynamic[(Clo*-0.7) + 0.7]], FontSize -> 9]
       }]},
    Alignment -> Center, Background -> None],
   Row[{"Clo = ", Dynamic[Clo], "    Cp = ", Dynamic[Cp], 
     "    Cprj = ", Dynamic[Cprj]}]}]]
```

This yields the result of the image below.
[image]

Here I clicked on "Origin" and "End of ...", the latter being the original formatting of the labels. Is there a way to actually disable the "End of ..." button while still having it display, if and only if `Clo=0`? I want to have it so that it is not possible to click on the grayed out option, but possible to toggle between the other two.

Comment: Do you get what you need if you replace the second `SetterBar` with `Row[MapThread[ Setter[Dynamic[{Cp, Cprj}], {#}, #2, Enabled -> #3] &,  {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}},   {Style["Origin of C", FontSize -> 9],Style[ "Tip of C", FontSize -> 9], Style["End of (A.B)A^",FontSize -> 9, FontColor -> GrayLevel[Dynamic[(Clo*-0.7) + 0.7]]]}, {True, True, Dynamic[Clo == 1]}}]]`?

Comment: Yes! that's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** Replace your second `SetterBar` with a row of individual setters and link `Enabled` option value for the third setter to the value of `Clo`:

```
DynamicModule[{Clo = 1, Cp = 0, Cprj = 0}, 
 Column[{Column[{Style["Location of C", FontSize -> 14], 
     SetterBar[Dynamic[Clo], {0 -> "Origin", 1 -> "Tip of B"}]}, 
      Alignment -> Center, Background -> None], 
   Column[{Style["Location of (A.C)" <> ToString[OverHat[A], StandardForm], 
       FontSize -> 14], 
     Row[MapThread[Setter[Dynamic[{Cp, Cprj}], {#}, #2, Enabled -> #3] &, 
         {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, 
          {Style["Origin of C", FontSize -> 12], Style["Tip of C", FontSize -> 12], 
           Style["End of (A.B)" <> ToString[OverHat[A], StandardForm], FontSize -> 12, 
            FontColor -> GrayLevel[Dynamic[-.7 Clo] + 0.7]]},
         {True, True, Dynamic[Clo == 1]}}]]}, 
      Alignment -> Center, Background -> None], 
   Row[{"Clo = ", Dynamic[Clo], "    Cp = ", Dynamic[Cp], 
     "    Cprj = ", Dynamic[Cprj]}]}, 
 Center, 2]]
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, add the option `Enabled -> True` to `SetterBar[...]` and post-process to inject `Dynamic[Clo == 1]` in desired position in box expression:

```
postProcess = RawBoxes @* 
   ReplaceAll[sb : SetterBox[_, {{0, 1}}, ___] :> 
      RuleCondition[sb /. True -> Dynamic[Clo == 1]]] @* 
   ToBoxes;

DynamicModule[{Clo = 1, Cp = 0, Cprj = 0}, 
 Column[{Column[{Style["Location of C", FontSize -> 14], 
     SetterBar[Dynamic[Clo], {0 -> "Origin", 1 -> "Tip of B"}]}, 
    Alignment -> Center, Background -> None], 
   Column[{Style["Location of (A.C)" <> ToString[OverHat[A], StandardForm], 
      FontSize -> 14], 
     postProcess @ SetterBar[Dynamic[{Cp, Cprj}], 
       {{0, 0} -> Style["Origin of C", FontSize -> 12], 
        {1, 0} -> Style["Tip of C", FontSize -> 12],
        {0, 1} -> Style[Style["End of (A.B)" <> ToString[OverHat[A], StandardForm], 
           FontSize -> 12], GrayLevel[Dynamic[(Clo*-0.7) + 0.7]]]}, 
       Enabled -> True]}, 
     Alignment -> Center, Background -> None], 
   Row[{"Clo = ", Dynamic[Clo], "    Cp = ", Dynamic[Cp], 
        "    Cprj = ", Dynamic[Cprj]}]}, 
  Center, 2]]
```

[image]